# Пытаюсь сделать слайдер на js. Хотелось бы понять, где в коде допущена ошибка (ошибки)

Tags: javascript, слайдер

Стараюсь сделать слайдер без прибегания к глобальным переменным, в которых хранится фиксированная длина картинки. Логика такая:

Получить все картинки из html, после получить ширину каждой и добавить в список. При нажатии на кнопку хранимый индекс картинки увеличивается на единицу, а left увеличивается на цифру из массива по этому индексу. Реализовать нажатие кнопки решил циклом, который перемещает картинку и останавливается посредством команды breake.

Код максимально снабдил комментариями. Возможно по ним будет проще отследить ошибку. Буду признателен ссылкам на литературу.

P.S. Имеется явная ошибка, т.е. консоль выводит сообщение `"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )"` в цикле функции slider.next. Но я полагаю дело не только в ней. Сам код:

```js
;
(function() {

  // берем индекс из массива. при нажатии на кнопку хранимый индекс картинки 
  // увеличивается на единицу, а left увеличивается на цифру из массива по этому индексу.
  // что-то типо псевдокода 
  // if жмакнули на кнопку
  // мы получили список картинок class = "listImg"
  // i индекс массива увеличился на 1
  // left увеличивается на ширину картинки (что есть i-й элемент массива list)

  // данная функция добавляет в себя необходимые компоненты вроде кнопок и тд. 
  // слово this делает все остальное тело функции контекстом (если я правильно понимаю)
  var slider = function() {
    var index = 1;
    this.btns = document.querySelectorAll(".btn"); // кнопки
    this.box = document.querySelector(".slider"); // div контейнер в котором хранится div, который в свою очередь хранит картинки
    this.slidesBox = document.querySelector(".listImg"); // div, который в свою очередь хранит картинки
    this.slides = document.querySelectorAll(".slide"); // картинки

    this.widthList = setImgWidth(); // поскольку функцию setImgWidth добавили в slider, то можно ее здесь запустить,
    // чтобы позже результат ее взять для slider.next или slider.prev
  }
  // предыдущую функцию немного переделал и тоже закинул в slider
  slider.setImgWidth = function() {
    //получаем все картинки в нужном блоке 
    var img = this.slidesBox;
    var list = [];
    //добавляем в массив ширину картинок
    for (var i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
      var width = img[i].clientWidth;
      list.push(width);
    }
    return list;
  }
  // добавляем новую функцию к функции slaider. Она добавляет обработчик нажатия кнопок 
  slider.indexPosition = function() {
    var max = this.btns.length; //количество кнопок

    for (var i = 0; i < max; i++) {
      this.btns[i].addEventListener("click", slider[this.btns[i].id].bind(null, this)); // Вот здесь сложная для меня херня, нашел в интернете. 
      // повесили обработчик, засунули его в функцию слайдер и при помощи bind 
    } // добавили доступ slider.prev и slider.next к объектам this в функции slider
  }
  // здесь обрабатываются нажатия на кнопки
  // в функцию slider добавляются еще две новые функции
  slider.prev = function() {
    /*var img = this.slidesBox;
    for ( index < img.length; index++ ) {
     slidesBox.style.left = +this.widthList[index] + "px";
     break; 
    }*/
  }

  slider.next = function() {
    // было принято решение сделать цикл, который берет значение переменной index
    // увеличивает его на едbницу, вместе с тем передвигает одну картинку на величину,
    // равную ширине картинки. после этого цикл прекращает работу. при этом index хранит 
    // в себе увеличенное значение 

    var img = this.slidesBox;
    for (index < img.length; index++) {
      slidesBox.style.left = -this.widthList[index] + "px";
      break;
    }
  }
})();
```

```css
.slider {
  display: block;
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.listImg {
  width: 9999px;
  position: relative;
  transition: all ease 1s;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.listImg img {
  float: left;
  margin: 0px 4px;
}


/*
    .listImg:after {
     content: "";
     display: block;
     clear: both;
    }*/

.btn-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 75px;
}

.btn {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 0 0;
  background-image: url("button/arrow.png");
}

.btn:nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title> Слайдер </title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="listImg">
      <img src="personLvl1.jpg" alt="" class="slide">
      <img src="personLvl2.jpg" alt="" class="slide">
      <img src="personLvl3.jpg" alt="" class="slide">
      <img src="personLvl4.jpg" alt="" class="slide">
      <img src="areal.jpg" alt="" class="slide">
      <img src="assemblyExperts.jpg" alt="" class="slide">
      <img src="middlePrice.jpg" alt="" class="slide">
      <img src="rgud.jpg" alt="" class="slide">
      <img src="searchRealties.jpg" alt="" class="slide">
      <img src="personLvl5.jpg" alt="" class="slide">
      <img src="personLvl6.jpg" alt="" class="slide">
      <img src="personLvl7.jpg" alt="" class="slide">
      <img src="personLvl8.jpg" alt="" class="slide">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-container">
    <div class="btn" id="nextSlide"></div>
    <div class="btn" id="prevSlide"></div>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Приведите в вопросе html и css, с которым ваш код должен работать.

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko, привел

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скрипт все еще не работает, т.к. он не дописан до конца, насколько я понимаю.

Все синтаксические(и не только) ошибки поправлены - смотрите комментарии.

Также на будущее могу порекомендовать, пока не наберете достаточно опыта(или просто сомневаетесь), проверяйте работоспособность кода как можно чаще. Написали команду - проверили как работает. А то у вас ошибки могу наслаиваться одна на другую и будет очень сложно их искать.

```js
(function() {

  // берем индекс из массива. при нажатии на кнопку хранимый индекс картинки 
  // увеличивается на единицу, а left увеличивается на цифру из массива по этому индексу.
  // что-то типо псевдокода 
  // if жмакнули на кнопку
  // мы получили список картинок class = "listImg"
  // i индекс массива увеличился на 1
  // left увеличивается на ширину картинки (что есть i-й элемент массива list)

  // данная функция добавляет в себя необходимые компоненты вроде кнопок и тд. 
  // слово this делает все остальное тело функции контекстом (если я правильно понимаю)
  var slider = function() {
    // ПОПРАВЛЕНО
    this.index = 1;
    this.btns = document.querySelectorAll(".btn"); // кнопки
    this.box = document.querySelector(".slider"); // div контейнер в котором хранится div, который в свою очередь хранит картинки
    this.slidesBox = document.querySelector(".listImg"); // div, который в свою очередь хранит картинки
    this.slides = document.querySelectorAll(".slide"); // картинки

    // ПОПРАВЛЕНО
    this.widthList = this.setImgWidth(); // поскольку функцию setImgWidth добавили в slider, то можно ее здесь запустить,
    // чтобы позже результат ее взять для slider.next или slider.prev
  }
  // предыдущую функцию немного переделал и тоже закинул в slider
  // ПОПРАВЛЕНО
  slider.prototype.setImgWidth = function() {
    //получаем все картинки в нужном блоке 
    var img = this.slidesBox;
    var list = [];
    //добавляем в массив ширину картинок
    for (var i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
      var width = img[i].clientWidth;
      list.push(width);
    }
    return list;
  }
  // добавляем новую функцию к функции slaider. Она добавляет обработчик нажатия кнопок 
  slider.prototype.indexPosition = function() {
    var max = this.btns.length; //количество кнопок

    for (var i = 0; i < max; i++) {
      this.btns[i].addEventListener("click", slider[this.btns[i].id].bind(null, this)); // Вот здесь сложная для меня херня, нашел в интернете. 
      // повесили обработчик, засунули его в функцию слайдер и при помощи bind 
    } // добавили доступ slider.prev и slider.next к объектам this в функции slider
  }
  // здесь обрабатываются нажатия на кнопки
  // в функцию slider добавляются еще две новые функции
  slider.prototype.prev = function() {
    /*var img = this.slidesBox;
    for ( index < img.length; index++ ) {
     slidesBox.style.left = +this.widthList[index] + "px";
     break; 
    }*/
  }

  slider.prototype.next = function() {
    // было принято решение сделать цикл, который берет значение переменной index
    // увеличивает его на едbницу, вместе с тем передвигает одну картинку на величину,
    // равную ширине картинки. после этого цикл прекращает работу. при этом index хранит 
    // в себе увеличенное значение 

    var img = this.slidesBox;
    // ПОПРАВЛЕНО
    for (; this.index < img.length; this.index++) {
      // ПОПРАВЛЕНО
      this.slidesBox.style.left = -this.widthList[index] + "px";
      break;
    }
  }
  // ПОПРАВЛЕНО
  var slider1 = new slider();
})();
```

```css
.slider {
  display: block;
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.listImg {
  width: 9999px;
  position: relative;
  transition: all ease 1s;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.listImg img {
  float: left;
  margin: 0px 4px;
}


/*
    .listImg:after {
     content: "";
     display: block;
     clear: both;
    }*/

.btn-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 75px;
}

.btn {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 0 0;
  background-image: url("button/arrow.png");
}

.btn:nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title> Слайдер </title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="listImg">
      <img src="personLvl1.jpg" alt="personLvl1" class="slide">
      <img src="personLvl2.jpg" alt="personLvl2" class="slide">
      <img src="personLvl3.jpg" alt="personLvl3" class="slide">
      <img src="personLvl4.jpg" alt="personLvl4" class="slide">
      <img src="areal.jpg" alt="areal" class="slide">
      <img src="assemblyExperts.jpg" alt="assemblyExperts" class="slide">
      <img src="middlePrice.jpg" alt="middlePrice" class="slide">
      <img src="rgud.jpg" alt="rgud" class="slide">
      <img src="searchRealties.jpg" alt="searchRealties" class="slide">
      <img src="personLvl5.jpg" alt="personLvl5" class="slide">
      <img src="personLvl6.jpg" alt="personLvl6" class="slide">
      <img src="personLvl7.jpg" alt="personLvl7" class="slide">
      <img src="personLvl8.jpg" alt="personLvl8" class="slide">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-container">
    <div class="btn" id="nextSlide">&lt;</div>
    <div class="btn" id="prevSlide">&lt;</div>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: спасибо за помощь, советы и правки. пойду дальше работать над кодом. возможно мне стоит упростить код, чтобы своей головой дописать его до конца

Answer (score 2):

В `for` должны быть три операции, разделенные `;`, - инициализация, условие продолжения, конец итерации - даже если какие-то из них пустые:

```
for (; index < img.length; index++) {
```

Не вижу в коде `new slider()`.